# How PHP Soap Client converts XML to a stdClass Object

Tags: php, soap-client

PHPs native soap client returns the XML response as a std class object. Can someone tell me how it is done, there has to be some inbuilt parse function to do that rt?

Comment: Insufficient information. Also, how is your question related to programming problem and what does **rt?** mean (at the end of your sentence)?

Comment: sorry about that. Just wanted to know how it is done

Comment: Well, since you're asking about a piece of PHP written in C, the only possible way to answer your question is to tell you where you can view the mentioned code. Usual tool, apart from github, is [lxr.php.net](http://lxr.php.net)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

And it uses libxml to parse the SOAP request:
[SourceCode](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/libxml)